# Why does the input element not fill the contents of the div?

Tags: html, css

Here is my existing view.

[image]

I do not understand why the textbox for "bbbbbbb" does not take the same width as column "aaaaa".

I set the border on the div and it clearly illustrates the width.

Why does the input element not fill the contents of the div?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="mtc">aaaaaa</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
            .Name("mtc")
            .DataValueField("aaa")
            .DataTextField("bbb")
            .Placeholder("Select Map Type Codes...")
            .AutoBind(false)
            .DataSource(src =>
            {
                src.Read("Action", "Controller");
            })
            )
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="bb">bbbbbbb</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" style="border:solid">
            <input type="text" style="width:100%;" class="k-textbox" id="bb" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please provide a codepin for your code , i can not figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: Works just fine with standard bootstrap http://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/BpNWaO would need to see your CSS containing `k-textbox` etc.

Comment: Unable to access codepin so I can't do that.

Comment: Doh!  The site.css has a max-width set on it.  I didn't even think to look at that.